# wording don't disapear vba

Tags: excel, vba, userform

HI I have the following code and it used to work but it no longer does. This is in a Userform:

```
 Private Sub First_Name_Nom_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Call RunFast_Begin
    Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Select
        If Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Range("C3").Value = "Nominator's First Name" Then
            [C3].Value = ""


    ElseIf Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Range("C3").Value = "" Then
        [C3].Value = "Nominator's First Name"
    End If
Call RunFast_End
End Sub
Private Sub First_Name_Nom_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Call RunFast_Begin
Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Select
    If Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Range("C3").Value = "Nominator's First Name" Then
        [C3].Value = ""

    ElseIf Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Range("C3").Value = "" Then
        [C3].Value = "Nominator's First Name"
    End If
Call RunFast_End
End Sub

Private Sub First_Name_Nom_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Call RunFast_Begin
Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Select
   If Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Range("C3").Value = "Nominator's First Name" Then
        [C3].Value = ""

    ElseIf Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Range("C3").Value = "" Then
        [C3].Value = "Nominator's First Name"
    ElseIf Range("C3").Value <> "Nominator's First Name" Then
    End If
Call RunFast_End
End Sub
```

here's the code for run fast beging and end

```
Public CalcState As Long
Public EventState As Boolean
Public PageBreakState As Boolean

Sub RunFast_Begin()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

'CalcState = Application.Calculation
'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False


'addition pour ce program
Sheets("List").Visible = True
Sheets("Prov").Visible = True
Sheets("Test").Visible = True
Sheets("Teste").Visible = True
Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Visible = True
Sheets("Nominees").Visible = True
Sheets("Nomes(es)").Visible = True



End Sub

Sub RunFast_End()

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
'Application.Calculation = CalcState
Application.EnableEvents = EventState
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'addition pour ce program
Sheets("List").Visible = False
Sheets("Prov").Visible = False
Sheets("Test").Visible = False
Sheets("Teste").Visible = False
Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Visible = False
Sheets("Nominees").Visible = False
Sheets("Nomes(es)").Visible = False
End Sub
```

So thechnically what it needs to do is that when someone clicks or double clicks on the First_Name_Nom text box of the userform the information written disappear to let the user write the first name. The elseif I understand is an extra because technically it should never be blank but it is just as a precaution.

Can anyone tell me why Nominator's First Name no longer disappear on click or double click by the user?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you expecting this code to clear the `Textbox`? Also, for changing a value in cells, qualifying your sheets should help (i.e. **`With Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`**

Comment: Yes I just want to textbox to be clear when the user click or double click on it. Should I put with thisworkbook.worksheet before  Sheets("TEST_Nominator").Select? I/m still a newbee in vba... I use it only from time to time... getting better at it but not an expert yet ;-)

Comment: Unless you have removed some code, your code (as it is here) clears the cell in a sheet and not the `textbox` in your userform. To clear the text, in your **First_Name_Nom_DblClick** sub, try something like this: `First_Name_Nom.Value = ""` or `Me.First_Name_Nom.Value = ""`

Comment: Thanks Zac, I'll try it out. Will keep you posted on the results :-)

Comment: Awesome!! it seems to work now. I used First_Name_Nom.Value = "" and First_Name_Nom.Value = "Nominator's First Name" on Exit. Thanks so much

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped

Comment: @Zac Want to put this in an Answer, or should we close as "no repro"?

Comment: Can just close it